# How to check if selector has qtip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, qtip

How can I check if an element is instantiated with a qtip plugin?

For example

```
$('input').qtip("hasqtip");
```

Comment: What vertion of qtip? 1 or 2?

Comment: I used version 1 of qtip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An very easy way would be to apply the plugin using a class selector like, in anchors

```
$("a.qtip").qtip(); //Apply qtip, to only those links with qtip class on them
```

Then, to check if a link has qtip on them, check their class

```
$('a').click(function() { //whenever a link is cliked
   if($(this).hasClass('qtip')) { //check if it has qtip class on them
     //if it has

     //SCREAM: yes i found a qtip :D 
   }
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, just to test I tried it in jsfiddle but aint working check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/dqkzV/9/ ; but good reply! :) cheers

Comment: @Tats_innit, You didn't understood my point. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/dqkzV/11/)

Comment: @Tats_innit see my answer.. I used your jsfiddle.. thanks.. :D

Comment: Yep, indeed! No complains! Perfect bruv! :) I did the same lol @Baz1nga :D

Comment: @Starx +1 to you as well mate!

Answer (score 13):

The authors suggested way to check for existence of qtip on an element is to use the following method:

```
if( 'object' === typeof $(elem).data('qtip') )
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/dqkzV/14/)**

Comment: yes indeed works for this one check here: (working version reside here) http://jsfiddle.net/dqkzV/13/ just sharing bruv! cheers!

Comment: Is there a way to set typeof value back to 'undefined' ??

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it

```
if($("#mybtn").attr("data-hasqtip")) {
$("#mybtn").qtip().destroy();
}
```

A qtip2 element will have an attribute data-hasqtip. If never instantiated or destroyed the attribute will be missing

e.g.

```
<button id="mybtn" class="infobtn" style="float: left; display: block;" data-hasqtip="2">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i>
</button>
```